# Agora cloud recording is not working. Start and acquire work normally, but I don't get any video files and query and stop return error 404

Tags: agora.io

I have problems with cloud recording. Right now I am testing it with postman. I call acquire, then start, start returns code 200 ok or code 201 created. Then, when I call query or stop they return code 404 not found. Why is this happening and how to fix this? Also, I'm not quite sure if I set correct key and secret key. I am using Azure, I created a storage resource and I have a tab with keys there. I just copied the key from the first key field and pasted it both to key and secret key variables. Am I doing it right or should I use some other keys?

[image: Azure keys screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Currently looking into why the stop api call is returning a 404, it's happening across all storage vendor options.

Answer (score 0):

```
  "recordingConfig": {"maxIdleTime": 86400} // - one day
```

add above line.
By default maxIdleTime set to one minute. Once you start the recording and the recording will be stopped after one minute. so you got 404 status code for both query and stop Api call